# How to get date-format with day + month name and GMT?

Tags: vb.net, date, format

I want to write the current date in the following format in VB.net:

```
Tue, 27 Jul 2010 00:00:00 GMT+02:00
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps simply:

```
Date.Now.ToString("R") ' Fri, 14 Nov 2014 12:32:18 GMT
```

[The RFC1123 ("R", "r") Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx#RFC1123)